# Does the equilibrium constant of an ideal liquid mixture reaction depend on pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, mixtures, reaction-control

I want to calculate the equilibrium constant K[T] for a the following reaction:

$$\ce{CH3OH(l) + C4H8(l) -> C5H12O(l)}$$

It is assumed that the mixture is ideal and the reaction takes place at 14 bar pressure.

K[T] is defined as the product of the thermodynamic activities to the power of the stoichiometric coefficient:

$$\prod_j {a_j^{\nu_j}} = \prod_j {\left(  \frac{\hat f_j[T, p, \mathbf{x}] }{ f_j^{\mathrm{ref}}[T, p^{\mathrm{ref}}, \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{ref}}]} \right)}^{\nu_j}$$

The fugacity is given by Raoult's law,

$$f_i = x_i \cdot p_i^{*}$$

where x is the molar fraction and p* the vapor pressure, which are given.

How can I determine the reference fugacity, and where in the calculations do I use the 14 bar pressure at which the reaction takes place?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9108/104336

Answer (score 0):

The equilibrium constant for a chemical reaction is only a function of temperature. However, if you want to calculate the equilibrium constant $K$ via an equilibrium calculation, e.g. using the equation you posted, then we need  to find the pressure dependence on the fugacity of the species $i$ as a liquid.

---

We write the relationship between the fugacity of a pure species $i$ with the Gibbs energy, for two different situations distinguished by a zero superscript
\begin{align}
  g_i   &= \Gamma(T) + RT\ln(f_i)   \tag{1} \\
  g_i^0 &= \Gamma(T) + RT\ln(f_i^0) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Subtracting Eq. (2) from Eq. (1)
$$ g_i - g_i^0 = RT\ln\bigg(\frac{f_i}{f_i^0}\bigg) \tag{3} $$
Equation (3) links two different states:

1. The fugacity of a pure species at pressure $p$ and temperature $T$.
2. The fugacity of a pure species at pressure $p^0$ and temperature $T$. The reference state for a pure liquid, in the context of this equation, is generally chosen as that where the substance at temperature $T$ is a **saturated liquid**, and thus $p^0 = p^\mathrm{sat}$.

Now we use the fundamental thermodynamic relation for pure substances
$$ \mathrm{d}g = v\mathrm{d}p - s\mathrm{d}T \tag{4} $$

The evolution $(p^\mathrm{sat},T)\to(p,T)$ at constant temperature, for a species labeled with $i$, is carried out by integrating Eq. (4)
$$ g_i - g_i^\mathrm{sat} = \int_{p_i^\mathrm{sat}}^p
   v_i\mathrm{d}p \tag{5} $$

The liquid molar volume will change between these two pressures. For a liquid, we make the assumption that if the pressure range is not that large, it will remain constant and equal to the *liquid saturated volume* at the saturation pressure $ v_i = v_i^\mathrm{sat} $. Hence, Eq. (5) turns into
$$ g_i - g_i^\mathrm{sat} = v_i^\mathrm{sat}(p - p^\mathrm{sat}) \tag{6} $$
Combining Eqs. (3) and (6)
\begin{equation}
  RT\ln\bigg(\frac{f_i}{f_i^\mathrm{sat}}\bigg) = v_i^\mathrm{sat}(p - p^\mathrm{sat})
  \to
  \frac{f_i}{f_i^\mathrm{sat}} = \exp\bigg[\frac{v_i^\mathrm{sat}
  (p - p_i^\mathrm{sat})}{RT}\bigg] \tag{7}
\end{equation}
The right-hand side of Eq. (7) is the famous **Poynting factor**.

---

We return to the equilibrium constant. As stated, the mixture is ideal. We deal with liquids, so the fugacity coefficient of species $ i $ in a mixture is $\hat{f}_i = x_i\gamma_if_i=  x_i f_i $, because $ \gamma_i = 1 $. Summarizing the reaction in the fashion $\ce{A + B -> C}$
\begin{equation}
  K = \dfrac{\dfrac{\hat{f}_C}{f_C^\mathrm{sat}}}
  {\left(\dfrac{\hat{f}_B}{f_B^\mathrm{sat}}\right)
   \left(\dfrac{\hat{f}_A}{f_A^\mathrm{sat}}\right)} =
  \dfrac{\dfrac{x_Cf_C}{f_C^\mathrm{sat}}}
  {\left(\dfrac{x_Bf_B}{f_B^\mathrm{sat}}\right)
   \left(\dfrac{x_Af_A}{f_A^\mathrm{sat}}\right)} \tag{8}
\end{equation}
Now we use Eq. (7) for the three ratios in Eq. (8)
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{K =
  \dfrac{x_C \exp\bigg[\dfrac{v_C^\mathrm{sat}
  (\color{blue}{p} - p_C^\mathrm{sat})}{RT}\bigg]}
  {x_A \exp\bigg[\dfrac{v_A^{sat}(\color{blue}{p} - p_A^{sat})}
  {RT}\bigg] \cdot
   x_B \exp\bigg[\dfrac{v_B^{sat}(\color{blue}{p} - p_B^{sat})}
  {RT}\bigg]}} \tag{9}
\end{equation}

In blue is emphasized the pressure dependence in the fugacity.

Eq. (9) shows that additional information is needed when we deal with liquid-phase reactions:

- The saturation pressure $p_i^\mathrm{sat}$ for every species.
- The saturated liquid molar volumes $v_i^\mathrm{sat}$ for every species, evaluated at $p_i^\mathrm{sat}$.

Comment: One book is [this one](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/J-M-Smith/dp/1259696529/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_es_US=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=SV7DQHJOBR0M&keywords=thermodynamics+van+ness&qid=1691963819&sprefix=thermodynamics+van+n%2Caps%2C304&sr=8-2) in chapters $10-13$, and [this one](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/John-Prausnitz/dp/0139777458/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_es_US=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3GR54EETLDUHO&keywords=prausnitz+molecular+thermodynamics&qid=1691964116&sprefix=prausnitz+molecular+thermodyna%2Caps%2C260&sr=8-1), chapter, $1$, $2$, and $7$.

Comment: Comments are for discussion of science content, please use the chat for extended discussion if you would like to have an extended discussion. See also https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4341/72973.