# Why isn't ΔG equal to zero for this equilibrium reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

In the reaction $\ce{E(g) <=> P(g)}$ at 25 °C, equilibrium is reached when the pressure of the product is 0.100 that of the reactant. What is $\Delta G$ in joules?

Using $\Delta G = RT\ln K$, my answer is $-8.31 \times 298 \times \ln (1.00) \ \text{J}$.
However, the answer is $-8.31 \times 298 \times \ln (0.100) \ \text{J}$. Wouldn't this mean that $\Delta G > 0$, therefore favoring the reactants? (As an aside, why would the reaction even be shifted to the left since it has a higher pressure?)

Comment: You need to look again. $\Delta G$ is negative.

Comment: Wouldn't the negative value from ln(0.100) cancel with the negative in front?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you changed from 1.0 to 0.1. But as it is stated, pressure of the products = 0.1 times the pressure of the reactants, which means there are more reactants.

Comment: Okay, that part makes sense. But then how does that correlate with the system being in equilibrium?

Comment: The value of $\Delta G$ does not indicate anything about equilibrium. But an example might be CH4 + 2H2O <==> CO2 + 4H2 under extreme pressure.

Comment: I don't understand; I thought $ΔG = 0$ indicated equilibrium, such as described here: http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch21/gibbs.php#relation

Comment: It's been too long and I tired. You're absolutely right.

Comment: The equation is different, the web page has $\Delta G° = \Delta G + RT$ ln $K$. $\Delta G$ is 0 at equilibrium, so $\Delta G°$ is $-RT$ ln $K$ or −8.31∗298∗ln(0.100) J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two different quantities. The equation you are using describes the standard Gibbs free energy of reaction $\Delta G^{0}$, i.e. $\Delta G$ for standard conditions without any requirement of the reaction being in equilibrium.
And this quantity can very well be different from zero.
For non-standard conditions the Gibbs free energy of reaction is

\begin{equation}
 \Delta G = \Delta G^{0} + RT \log K
\end{equation}

and as you stated correctly this quantity must (per definition) be equal to zero for equilibrium conditions.

For a derivation see [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5814/189) of mine.