# Why is the equilibrium constant unaffected by a change of the initial concentration?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

In my class, it was taught that the equilibrium constant does not vary with 
the intial concentration of the reactants? Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the math tells you that the equilibrium constant is independent of the initial compositions:

For $a\mathrm{A}+b\mathrm{B}\rightarrow c\mathrm{C}+d\mathrm{D}$,
$$K_c=\frac{[\mathrm{C}]^c[\mathrm{D}]^d}{[\mathrm{A}]^a[\mathrm{B}]^b}$$
where $[\mathrm{C}]$, $[\mathrm{D}]$, $[\mathrm{A}]$, and $[\mathrm{B}]$ are concentrations *at equilibrium*.

This makes some sense intuitively: the rate of the reaction is dependent only on the present concentrations of compounds (and some other stuff like pressure and temperature), not previous concentrations. And equilibrium is defined as a position where the rate of forward and backward reactions are the same.

Comment: I have an another question too..Why equilibrium constant is proportional to concentration alone???

Comment: @anilbabu What else would you expect it to be proportional to?

Comment: temperature, pressure,etc

Comment: @anilbabu Exactly. Those are the two other predominant factors. Increasing the pressure moves the equilibrium position towards the side with a smaller number of molecules (assuming all gaseous). Increasing the temperature pushes towards the endothermic direction. Look at Le Chatelier’s
principle for some more stuff.

Comment: This is a first order approximation for ideal dilutions only. If the initial concentration becomes large, $K_c\propto K$ breaks down.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Sounds interesting; I just searched online quickly, and I didn't find anything about it (largely because I was unsure what to search for). Do you have any links to stuff about that?

Comment: @Martin - マーチン I never knew that $\ce{Kc}$ was an approximation. Can you please elaborate on the actual result then?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN The statement that $K_c$ or $K$ doesn't vary with initial concentration is an approximation; and $K_c$ is an approximation to $K$. Maybe my answer here helps [What kind of equilibrium constant we use for Gibbs free energy and Van't Hoff equation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/13645/4945) (But I have no time to explain this further.)