# Is the equilibrium constant in the expression based on pressure or concentration?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

$$\Delta G^\circ=-RT\ln K$$

I have always assumed it to be $K_p$ because $\Delta G^\circ$ represents standard free energy change and the standard state for a gas is 1 bar. So I thought we must express the activities of gases as ratios of partial pressures to $\pu{1 bar}$. But while solving sums, I found my answer to match only if I consider $K$ as $K_c$. Where am I wrong? Or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Your question is indeed natural to arise, but I think it's way complicated than it seems. [Read more here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10084/5026).

Comment: Sure thing! I don’t understand a word in that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. It is exactly what is given there $K$, the standard equilibrium constant, and the equation given is its definition,
$$\Delta G^\circ=-RT\ln K.\tag{1}\label{def}$$

A general equilibrium constant for any reaction 
$$\ce{\nu_A A + \nu_B B + \nu_C C + \cdots 
   <=>\nu_{A'} A' + \nu_{B'} B' + \nu_{C'} C' + \cdots  }$$
is given by
$$K_x = \frac{ x_{\ce{A'}}^{\ce{\nu_{A'}}}\cdot x_{\ce{B'}}^{\ce{\nu_{B'}}}\cdot
               x_{\ce{C'}}^{\ce{\nu_{C'}}}\cdots}{
               x_{\ce{A}}^{\ce{\nu_A}}\cdot x_{\ce{B}}^{\ce{\nu_B}}\cdot
               x_{\ce{C}}^{\ce{\nu_C}}\cdots},$$
or more general, gathering all components in $\mathbb{B}=\{\ce{A, B, C, \dots, A', B', C', \dots }\}$
$$K_x = \prod_{B~\in~\mathbb{B}} x_B^{\nu_B}.\tag2$$

If you insert that into \eqref{def}, then $x$ becomes the chemical potential of the component. You can derive the link to the activity of the component (see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5814/4945)), and you can link the activity to concentrations, pressures, etc.

Given the right boundary conditions, e.g. ideal dilution, $K$ essentially becomes $K_c$, etc.

$$\mu(i) \propto a(i) \propto c(i) \implies K \propto K_c\tag3$$

Obviously, this is a very sloppy generalisation, and you should study thermodynamics in more detail to fully understand the differences between the quantities used, and when to use which.

Comment: x is never equal to chemical potential.  I think you meant activity (or perhaps fugacity).  Chemical potential is partial molar free energy, and has units of energy per mile.

Comment: "ideal dilution" Do you mean _infinite dilution_ i.e. the Kohlaurcsh law limit of ionic conductivity in electrochemistry? (that's a very vague connection though)

Comment: Although the OP has accepted the answer, I don't see how this answers the question. It does not tell when to use which type of equilibrium constant.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Martin does say that "you should study thermodynamics in more detail to fully understand the differences between the quantities used, and **when to use which**" (my emphasis) i.e. without knowing the exact specific conditions it is difficult to predict if it is $K_\mathrm{c}$ or $K_\mathrm{p}$ or a hybrid of both.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Then how are we expected to use the equilibrium constants in problems that we are expected to solve?

Comment: Yep, I wonder the same...  @Martin Can you help here?

Comment: I agree @ApoorvPotnis I accepted the answer for the aforesaid reasons. Is there something like for an equilibrium with only gases, we should use $\pu{K_p}$  and for other equilibria we use $\pu{K_c}$?

Answer (score 2):

With gas phase reactions the equation for equilibrium is $\Delta G^\mathrm{o} =-RT\ln(K_p)$ where because the equilibrium constant $K_p$ may be defined in terms of the free energies in their standard states (as you mention), i.e. at 1 bar (or atm.) it must be independent of pressure.

In terms of the partial pressures if the reaction has species $M_i$ the general  reaction is $\ce{v_1M_1 + v_2M_2<=>v_3M_3 + v_4M_4}$ then, with $p_i$ being the partial pressure of species $i$, $K_p = \prod p_i^{v_i}$ where the stoichiometric coefficients are $v_i$, and are positive for products and negative for reactants, thus for the reaction $\ce{A_2<=>2A}$, $K_p= p_A^2/p_{A_2}$.

The equilibrium constant can also be defined in terms of concentration since for a perfect gas the partial pressure of the $i^{\text{ th}}$ species is $p_i=n_iRT/V=c_iRT$. The new equilibrium constant ($K_c = \prod c_i^{v_i}$) when written in terms of $K_p$ becomes  $\displaystyle K_c=K_p(RT)^{-\Sigma v_i}$ which is often written as $\displaystyle K_c=K_p(RT)^{-\Delta n}$ where $\Delta n= \Sigma v_i$. Thus for the reaction $\ce{2A + 3B<=> 4C}$, $\Delta n\equiv \Sigma v_i= -2-3+4=-1$ and so $\displaystyle K_c=RTK_p$

(Incidentally, the *temperature* dependence if the equilibrium constant $K_p$ is given by the Van't Hoff equation, sometimes called the Van't Hoff Isochore).