# Why is the concentration of gases denoted in form of partial pressure?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, concentration

In most of the chemical laws of chemistry involving concentration of products or reactants like equilibrium constant, reaction quotient, Henry's law, Nernst equation etc, I often see a similar note stating **concentration of gas to be taken as partial pressures of that gas** or something similar to that. **So, Why is the concentration of gases denoted in form of partial pressure ?**

Does it have any relation with Dalton's law?

I don't know why this equation has been closed and it is not the duplicate of [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91423/112102) Please review again.

Comment: My guess would be that pressure is much easier to measure for a gas. Of course once you have the pressure, temperature and ideal gas equation would give you the concentration too. Also, concentration term, if replaced by partial pressure, will give you $\ce{K_p}$, not $\ce{K_c}$. Both terms are different.

Comment: Considering gas pressure is much more common than gas concentration. There is the relation for ideal gases $p=cRT$. The point is, many gas behaviour quantitatively depends rather on partial pressure than on concentration.

Comment: In addition to what TRC states, it can be mentioned that, in thermodynamics, concentration is not a fundamental parameter. Pressure is fundamental : it exists in the definition of the work, which is the very beginning of thermodynamics. $K_\mathrm{p}$ can be directly obtained , and has the correct dimension. On the contrary,$K_ \mathrm{c}$ is indirectly obtained, and the concentration have to be divided by a reference value of concentration

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise that concentrations and partial pressures are interchangeable or identical entities, which is not true. Fundamentally different physical quantities cannot "*take form*" of one another. The question I marked as a dupe is not a *literal* duplicate, but it explicitly reveals this flaw and the accepted answer by Martin can be used to answer this question of yours as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with the derivation of the equation for the equilibrium constant of an ideal gas phase reaction in terms of the standard change in Gibbs free energy?