# Why is the equilibrium constant given in litre per mole?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

> At $800\:\mathrm{K}$ a reaction mixture contained $0.5\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{SO2}$, $0.12\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{O2}$ and $5\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{SO3}$ at equilibrium. $K_\mathrm c$ for the equilibrium $$\ce{2SO2 + O2 -> 2SO3}$$ is $833\:\mathrm{L/mol}$. If the volume of the container is $1\:\mathrm{L}$, calculate how much $\ce{O2}$ is to be added at this equilibrium in order to get $5.2\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{SO3}$ at the same temperature.

The answer comes out to be $0.34\:\mathrm{mol}$.

I have understood the whole question and I am getting the answer. I just have a confusion why we are taking $K_\mathrm c$ as $833$ and not $1/833$ which makes it $\mathrm{mol/L}$. I think $K_\mathrm c$ should be in $\mathrm{mol/L}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$K_\mathrm c$ is defined as (for more information see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5814/189))

\begin{equation}
 K_{c} = \prod_i [c_{i}]^{\nu_{i}} = \frac{\prod \limits_{i \in \text{products}} [c_{i}]^{|\nu_{i}|}}{\prod \limits_{j \in \text{reactants}} [c_{j}]^{|\nu_{j}|}}
\end{equation}

where $\nu_{i}$ and $c_{i}$ are the stochiometric coefficient and the concentration of the $i^{\text{th}}$ component in the reaction, respectively.

If you use this definition for the reaction

\begin{equation}
  \ce{2SO2 + O2 -> 2SO3}
\end{equation}

you get

\begin{equation}
 K_\mathrm c = \frac{[\ce{SO3}]^2}{[\ce{SO2}]^{2} [\ce{O2}]}
\end{equation}

where the notation $[i] = c_{i}$ was used.
This equation tells you that $K_\mathrm c$ has the unit

\begin{equation}
 \text{unit of }K_\mathrm c = \frac{\left(\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}} \right)^{2}}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}} \right)^{2} \left(\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}} \right)} = \frac{\mathrm{L}}{\mathrm{mol}} \ .
\end{equation}