# Dissociation percentages of N2O4 at different pressures using Gibbs' free energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

> \begin{align}
> \ce{N2O4(g)&<=>2NO2(g)} & 
> \Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ &= \pu{4.7 kJ mol^-1}
> \end{align}
>
> Knowing that the standard values for pressure and temperature are $\pu{1 bar}$ and $\pu{298 K}$ respectively, find:
>
> a) the dissociation grade (noted as $\alpha$) of $\ce{N2O4}$ at equilibrium, in standard conditions
>
> b) the dissociation grade of $\ce{N2O4}$ at equilibrium and at $\pu{298 K}$ / $\pu{10 bar}$

First, we find $K$ from $\Delta G$

Then we write the partial pressures as the molar fraction of the compound times the total pressure of the system (at equilibrium)

After that, we write the relation for $K_p$ using partial pressures

and I'm stuck...

\begin{align}
  \Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ &= -RT \ln K &
  \Rightarrow K&=0.15 \mathrm{~(unitless)} 
  \\
  P_{\ce{N2O4}} &= \frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\cdot P & 
  P_{\ce{NO2}}  &= \frac{2\alpha}{1+\alpha}\cdot P & 
  K_p = \frac{(P_{\ce{NO2}})^2}{P_{\ce{N2O4}}} 
  \\
  \Rightarrow K_p &= \frac{4\alpha^2}{1-\alpha^2}\cdot P  
\\
\end{align}

My question is: how can I convert between $K$ (which is unitless) and $K_p$ (which is not) so that I can find the dissociation grade at $\pu{1 bar}$ and $\pu{10 bar}$?

Comment: See my answer to this recent question: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/40586/16683 The short answer is that the dimensionless $K$ is calculated using $p_i/p^\circ$ instead of $p_i$, where $p^\circ = 1~\mathrm{bar}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I looked it up first, but I somehow managed to miss that post.

Comment: Don't worry about it, there are a ton of questions here about equilibrium constants and Gibbs free energies which are difficult to search.