# Why does the pressure equilibrium constant exist?

Tags: equilibrium

Since $K_c$ can already be used for calculating the equilibrium constant for a reaction involving gases, but $K_p$ cannot be used for calculating the equilibrium constant for a reaction involving aqueous solutions, what is the use for $K_p$?

It doesn't seem like there is ever a situation where $K_c$ cannot be used and $K_p$ must be used, especially since partial pressures can be readily converted to concentration through the ideal gas law. If anything, it just seems like the existence of *two equilibrium constants* that *more often than not don't equal each other* could cause more confusion.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's easier to use $\mathrm{K_p}$ rather than $\mathrm{K_c}$ in cases pertaining to gaseous equilibrium.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40567/which-equilibrium-constant-is-appropriate-to-use highly descripted.

Comment: It depends on what units you use, if pressure is measured then use $K_p$, if concentration  then $K_c=K_p(RT)^{-\Delta n}$ where $\Delta n$ is the change in the number of moles of gaseous substances as the reaction goes from left to right and $p$ is the total pressure. If mole fraction $K_x=K_pp^{-\Delta n}$.

Comment: @porphyrin isn't that just derived from the ideal gas law, like I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Ah... so it actually does make a difference. Thanks @akgnit.

Comment: @KarmanyaGB Sorry, this isn't a duplicate. That question asks whether the $K$ in $\Delta G^\circ = -RT \ln K$ stands for $K_p$ or $K_c$. This question does not even once mention that equation, and is in fact, a different question.

Comment: @GaurangTandon true, but that answers why the pressure equilibrium constant exists. Its the one that is correct (under certain assumptions) for gases and Kc would not work in that equation.